# Multiple currency exchange rate multiplication with user input value

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have multiple currency and its values in different list and Currency is lookup in the main list so user can select from dropdown and can enter its cost.

Main List field:

Currency- Lookup in main list. Currency list has currency field and exchange rate field which is number type field: user needs to select currency from dropdown options in main list

Cost - Number type: user need to enter values here

Based on the above inputs from user. I want to calculate Expected Cost

Expected Cost: exchange rate*Cost. Expected cost change when user change currency or cost.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test, this requirement can be achieved，need to set one-step workflow.

Please refer to this post for more information:
[SharePoint List calculated column formula](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c8c7b12-0478-4c55-9b22-505bfeb379b8/sharepoint-list-calculated-column-formula?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Note that in SPO, workflow2010 has been deprecated, and workflow2013 can be used instead:
[image]

============================

Currency List:

[image]

Main List:

[image]